# Visual C++ 2010 Express use command line arguments

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2010, command-line-arguments

I'm new to Visual C++ 2010, but I'm getting into it. I used the wizard to create a winform project with main and Form1 section. So far the program is running perfect. Now I'd like to use some command line arguments when starting the application.

The wizard created this main code:

```
;using namespace HVBackup2012;

[STAThreadAttribute]

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)

{
    // Aktivieren visueller Effekte von Windows XP, bevor Steuerelemente erstellt werden
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

    // Hauptfenster erstellen und ausführen
    Application::Run(gcnew Form1());
    return 0;
}
```

But I dont know, how to handle the args and hand it to Form1 to process it? I can not find this main construct at the internet at all, but it must be default? I don't unterstand the

```
(array<System::String ^> ^args).
```

Thanks for your Help

Lex

Comment: Managed C++ (or C++/CLI) is probably not the best way to learn C++ or Visual Studio. If you're not tied to C++ but want to use Windows Forms, it will be much easier to learn using one of the managed languages like VB or C# (I recommend C#).

Comment: Pass arguments through the constructor.  Add one to the Form1 class.